# Is there a way to change to parent of parent using command

Tags: windows, command-line

cd .. only backs one level, how to back multiple level quickly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
cd ..\..
```

to go two levels, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`cd \` should bring you all the way up to the root of the drive (for example from c:\foo\bar\rab\oof\ to c:\)